# Find all f that satisfy $\int_{a-1}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n) $ for every integers a,b where b>a.

Tags: calculus, functions

I am looking for ways how to generate functions that satisfy the property of area under the function between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ happens to  equal  $f(n+1)$. Additionally, I would like to now where to find some sources regarding this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A subset of these functions will be Step functions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: This is not functional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Foreman says, start with a step function.
One option, to make the function continuous, is to add a different quadratic $Q_n(x)$ for each $n$
$$Q_n(x)=(f(n)-f(n+1))P(x-n)$$
where $P(x)$ is the quadratic with 
$$P(0)=1,P(1)=0,\int_0^1P(t)dt=0$$
Then you can add multiples of $\sin2\pi kx$ without changing $f(n)$.
Another option is cubic splines, which make the function differentiable.